# java.io.FileNotFoundException:(The system cannot find the path specified) after a machine move

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I was working on an application fine on my laptop, backed up the project using subversion on java.net, downloaded it onto my desktop to carry on working and I am now getting this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\printing~subversion\fileupload\buildweb\resources\Directory Files\directoryFiles.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

But if you paste in the path into windows file explorer it opens up the file as it should.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Sorry i should have added, i have clean and build the project and still have the issue

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are actually accessing the file

Comment: Have you checked if the file really exists to begin with? Also, does you Java program/app has enough permissions to access to this file?

Comment: Found the issue !, there was a / missing from the path, clean and build all working now, cheers for the tips !